# Verify that a private method was NOT executed JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have looked around for this question a bit and have not found exactly what I need. I have learned a bit more about JMockit and mocking. Which is good. Seems like everyone wants to know how to make sure something has executed. I would like to learn the opposite.

Ok - I am writing a test to check a not so happy path in a public method. The method that is being tested is `void` so I can't really `assert` the results. **What I would like to do is verify that a method was NOT executed in this test case.**

For example:

```
class ClassToTest {
  private void method(String arg){}

  public void publicMethod(String arg0, String arg1){
    if(false){
      //this method should never get called.
      method(arg0);
    }
  }
}

class TestingClass{
  @Tested
  private ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest();

  @Test
  public void testCheckingIfPrivateMethodWasCalled(){
    classToTest.publicMethod("string1", "string2");

    new Verifications() {
      {
        //At this point I am trying something like
        Deencapsulation.invoke(classToTest, "method", "string1");
        times = 0; //Also tried maxTimes = 0;
        //Through debug it looks like the invoke is doing what it's named...
        //invoking the private method, I don't want to invoke.
        //How do I check that ClassToTest#method was not called?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am getting as results for the test case is a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter`. Which is on the line of `times = 0;`.

I know the `invoke` is executing the private method. I am left scratching my head trying to figure out how to "check" that said method is called with out invoking/executing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Test the state of your application. If the invocation of your private method is important, it should have affected state somewhere, and you should be able to test for it. Barring that, maybe consider giving the method default visibility (aka package-protected) so that your test can verify it. (That's assuming that your test lives in the same package as the class you're testing, which is a reasonable assumption.)

Comment: *Never* mock a `private` method, there's just no good reason to do so. Just think about it: private methods can be created or inlined at any time by developers that care about quality. Do you really want to have to modify working tests while you improve the production code through functionality-preserving refactorings? Even if you don't care about that, consider that other developers in the team or in the future might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is with the MockUp API for [faking](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import org.junit.Test;

import mockit.Mock;
import mockit.MockUp;
import mockit.Tested;

public class TestingClass {

    @Tested
    private ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest();

    @Test
    public void testCheckingIfPrivateMethodWasCalled() {
        PrivateMethodCheckMockUp mockUp = new PrivateMethodCheckMockUp() {
            @Mock
            private void method(String arg) {
                calledPrivate = true;
            }
        };

        classToTest.publicMethod("string1", "string2");

        assertFalse(mockUp.calledPrivate);
    }

    class PrivateMethodCheckMockUp extends MockUp<ClassToTest> {
        boolean calledPrivate = false;

        @Mock
        private void method(String arg) {
            calledPrivate = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are mocking a instance of the class then mocking the method on that class? What do you mock `PrivateMethodCheckMockUp#method` twice?

Comment: Actually `ClassToTest` is mocked only once, `@Tested` does not create a mock, "JMockit can help by automatically instantiating this class, and optionally injecting the relevant mocked dependencies. This is what the @Tested annotation is for."

Comment: Then I do mock its private method by using the `MockUp` API and use a flag to know whether it's been called or not (maybe with `Assert.fail()` it would have sufficed).